# how to replace all rows in a particular column with another string in r?

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file like

data.csv

```
Identity,CampaignName,Adgroupname
12,abc1,asterix
13,abc2,asterix1
frere,abc3,asterix2
xrert,dasa,trete
14,tytyt,ababa
```

Where the first row are the headers of the CSV file.

In the above CSV file if 'rer' appears in a string in 'Identiity' column then replace the whole string with '17' . for example 'frere' will be '17'. I can use 'gsub' to  replace 'rer' , but how to replace the whole string with another string? New to R, any help is appreciated.

My desired output

```
Identity,CampaignName,Adgroupname
12,abc1,asterix
13,abc2,asterix1
17,abc3,asterix2
17,dasa,trete
14,tytyt,ababa
```

Comment: will it replace 'frere' with '17' ?

Comment: @BenBolker :  It did not work. Any other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

```
dat <- read.csv(
   text=
"Identity,CampaignName,Adgroupname
12,abc1,asterix
13,abc2,asterix1
frere,abc3,asterix2
xrert,dasa,trete
14,tytyt,ababa")
```

By default the `Identity` column is a factor, and you can't introduce new strings into a factor:

```
 dat$Identity[grepl("rer",dat$Identity)] <- "17"
 ## Warning message:
 ## In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, grepl("rer", dat$Identity), value = c(1L,  :
 ##   invalid factor level, NA generated
```

You can either use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when you read the data, or (starting from the *original* data set)

```
 dat$Identity <- as.character(dat$Identity)
 dat$Identity[grepl("rer",dat$Identity)] <- "17"
```

You may then want to convert the column back into a numeric variable:

```
 dat$Identity <- as.numeric(dat$Identity)
```

Comment: I have up voted it because it has partially worked for me. It was introducing NAs , coereced data it was saying, but I have worked my way around to get the answer, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Works perfectly for the dataset that you've provided. Please provide a dataset that reproduces your coercion to NA.